# Getting a player-name using it's UUID

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I code java, and I'm making a minecraft bukkit plugin using the 1.8 spigot api. How to return a player's name, only knowing his / her uuid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getPlayer` method accepts a UUID:

```
Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid).getName();
```

Comment: @Zahachos If you only their UUID in a String, you could construct a `UUID` Object by using `UUID.fromString(uuidString)`

Comment: @Jojodmo True, true, but I didn'e need to in this case... thanks though!